# Postgres Sql : Need to add data from a single JSON input param to 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, postgresql

Below is the JSON object which when passed as a single param, needs to be added into 2 different tables. How can the mapping be done so that I can add data from JSON into tables as required?

**Tables** : *Item, ItemDetails*

**Json Input**: *Given below*

```js
{
  "orderId": "s",
  "fulfillerId": "qaqj8fkbmb",
  "orderDetailsUrl": "asd",
  "items": [
    {
      "dTe": "laseIn",
      "itemDescription": "Tetesting",
      "itemId": "item_1",
      "manufacturingUrl": "https://uploads_1.documents.press",
      "skuCode": "1223",
      "productName": "Tesing",
      "quantity": 225,
      "taskId": "task_ID_1"
    },
    {
      "dTe": "laseIn",
      "itemDescription": "Test Sku for Oracle testing",
      "itemId": "item_2",
      "manufacturingUrl": "https://uploads_2.documents.press",
      "skuCode": "123",
      "productName": "Test Sku for Oracle testing",
      "quantity": 225,
      "taskId": "task_ID_2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Desired Output**:

*Item Table*

- itemId
- fullfillerId
- orderId
- skuCode

++ all remaining data from JSON in Item Table

*ItemDetails Table*

- itemId
- orderDetailsUrl
- taskId
- quantity

I have tried various jsonb formatting but exact output is not achieved after parsing, I am not able to pick values from JSON and use Insert query

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the definition of the two target tables and an explanation what should go where

Comment: So for the given JSON you want to create two rows in the item table and one row in the item details table?

Comment: For both tables there will be 2 rows as there are 2 different items both will 2 rows

Comment: I only see one orderDetailsUrl not two different ones

Comment: There is only one order which has 2 different items in that order , so every item has orderURL for reference to  which order it belongs